# Session is not set if relocated in ColdFusion / Railo

Tags: coldfusion, facebook-oauth, railo

I am trying to achieve some basic OAuth Facebook login from my site.

Right before I redirect a user, I set a session variable which I then check once they've been returned to my site.

I can get to Facebook, login and then be returned, but once I am, the session variable does not exist.

I am absolutely stumped! Consider this code:

```
lock scope="session" type="exclusive" timeout="30" {
    session.source["state"] = createUUID();
}

// BUG?
// http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/missing-session-variables-using-cflocation.html
if ( isDefined("session.source.state") ) {

    location(url="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=#application.fbappid#&redirect_uri=#application.fbredirecturl#&state=#session.source["state"]#&scope=email,publish_actions", addtoken="true");

}
```

Funny thing is... `session.source["state"]` is passed in the URL to Facebook...but on return, it appears it has gone!

This is some really weird behaviour.

Redirecting with Javascript is not an option. It needs to be server-side.

Anyone have a clue on this? I'm using Railo.

Thanks,
Mikey.

Comment: First, in real life the session might time out if the user is on facebook long enough.  Second, cfdump your session scope to see what actually is there.

Comment: @DanBracuk The relocation happens, so session is defined and dumping it before redirect shows a UUID as expected. I am not on Facebook more than 10 seconds and sessions are set to 30 minutes. In addition, other session vars still work set elsewhere on the website. Dumping the session on return shows other vars, but not the one created prior to the redirect.

Comment: Is this happening on a secure (https) server? See https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RAILO-2773

Answer (score 1):

what is the callback url that facebook is returning the user to? reason I ask is that maybe you are redirecting the user to a different application.

the best thing todo is to dump application.applicationname on the page setting the session and the page that the user is returned to. make sure that they match up, otherwise the session will not carry over.

Answer (score 0):

> Funny thing is... `session.source["state"]` is passed in the URL to Facebook

This is not supposed to happen to session vars.  There must be something wrong.  Please trace your code, or post more code.

Comment: Ahh, but it is. I have confirmed that the session is checked, then passed to Facebook, then...on redirect back...session.source["state"] is not found. It totally dies. I believe this to be an issue with cflocation (location). See the link in my comment of the code. Is this still a relevant bug? If so, how to get around it on the server side?

Comment: @MichaelGiovanniPumo I think as long as your session is already started before you do cflocation, your user should not have a problem getting CFID/CFTOKEN set on their browser.  When they come back, as long as the right combo of CFID/CFTOKEN is sent, CF can fetch the correct session.  However, nothing in session should be passed along in the URL as text.

Comment: I have tried both addtoken="true" and addtoken="false", but neither seems to work. Is this what you were referring to?